# Improve Image Comparison Function

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on Visual Inspection System. One of my key function is to compare an image captured with an image from a data base. The comparison would reveal missing parts or damaged part. I have tried using pixel comparison, but this method is not reliable as it needs exactly similar image captured every time. Is there a way to improve this function to be more versatile. In a way it has to detect the difference in image even if the image captured is slightly offset or rotated. Please guide me using VB.Net. Below is my current code.

```
   Private Sub btnGo_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, _
 ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnGo.Click
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    Application.DoEvents()
    ' Load the images.
    Dim bm1 As Bitmap = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\pnasguna\Desktop\A56.jpg")
    Dim bm2 As Bitmap = Image.FromFile("C:\Users\pnasguna\Desktop\A54.jpg")
    ' Make a difference image.
    Dim wid As Integer = Math.Min(bm1.Width, bm2.Width)
    Dim hgt As Integer = Math.Min(bm1.Height, bm2.Height)
    Dim bm3 As New Bitmap(wid, hgt)
    ' Create the difference image.
    Dim are_identical As Boolean = True
    Dim eq_color As Color = Color.White
    Dim ne_color As Color = Color.Red
    For x As Integer = 0 To wid - 1
        For y As Integer = 0 To hgt - 1
            If bm1.GetPixel(x, y).Equals(bm2.GetPixel(x,y)) Then
                bm3.SetPixel(x, y, eq_color)
            Else
                bm3.SetPixel(x, y, ne_color)
                are_identical = False
            End If
        Next y
    Next x
    ' Display the result.
    PictureBox1.Image = bm3
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
    If (bm1.Width <> bm2.Width) OrElse (bm1.Height <> bm2.Height) Then are_identical =False
    If are_identical Then
        MessageBox.Show("The images are identical")
    Else
        MessageBox.Show("The images are different")
    End If
    bm1.Dispose()
    bm2.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: This effectively is doing image recognition. I think you'd probably better look into specialised tools for doing this kind of thing...

Comment: @yu_ominae Are you suggesting keypoint matching via OpenCV ? or Using histogram, as both seems to be a bit complicated. Is there a way rather than highlighting the difference between an image without using color method. Instead, just leave only difference in image displayed and turn the similar image to white or faded. Hope you get my point.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, because I am not an image processing expert unfortunately. But yes, if you want to cope with images which are slightly offset and want to match those I don't think there is an easy method for doing that. For finding differences between images, one method I have used in the past (for doing fluid flow visualisation) is normalising one image by another and then remap to a different colour scale. All differences will give you a colour value of less than 1. You can remap that to a colour scale of your choice and the differences really pop out.

Comment: The problem with this method is that if the images aren't very similar everything will show up as a difference... The main features shown in the image should at least overlap, otherwise it is just useless. But so will be every other comparison method you can possibly try.

Comment: @yu_ominae exactly, I'm facing this similar problem. As in the real life application it would be near to impossible to take a constant 100% similar image every time. Plus my camera would be mounted in a moving jig.

Comment: Actually, the images do not need to be 100% the same, they just need to be similar. To give you an example: If you are filming a car and want to compare differences between two frames, you would have to ensure that the car is (nearly) in the same position in the frame. As long as that is respected, you would be able to visualise the smaller differences. The problem with large differences is that EVERYTHING becomes different and there is no point in doing a comparison anymore, because you would not be able to extract anything meaningful beyond the fact that "there are a lot of differences".

Comment: As an example of the technique I have been using, see this link http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0894177711002287 I'm sorry it is the only link I can find showing an example. The fourth image in the figures and tables section on the right shows the type of visualisation you can achieve using normalisation. it shows the base image (a glass tank) on the left, the image to compare (the full tank) in the middle, and the differences between the two mapped to a 256 colour scale.

Comment: @yu_ominae you got a point there. Is there a way to give more than two colors in an image. Lets say, if I want the major difference to be in one color and minor difference in one color. while the similar image to be left alone.

Comment: thanks for the link, im looking it now

Comment: unfortunately I could not view the image from the link. Is there a way for me try out this visualization technique. any example codings. thanks

Comment: Sorry, no. This is an image from a journal article I wrote and unfortunately it is not available for free (thanks Elsevier!), but it was just meant as an example. In principle, all you do is divide the pixel values one be the other (you can convert the image to 256 colours first to help make this quicker) and then show the resulting scaled-colour image to the user or process that. The result will be like a topographic a map of the differences. It would be quick to code up I think.

Comment: Sory for the late reply. i see, so i need to convert the image into 256 colours than plot it into a topographic map. does this method takes a long time process.

Comment: It will depend on the size of your images of course, but I wouldn't think it should take too long. You should also be able to take advantage of multiple processors to do this faster. Saying that, the library in the answer below seems to achieve the same thing and you wouldn't have to do much extra coding, so definitely worth looking at I'd say.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could take the [XnaFan ImageComparison](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/374386/Simple-image-comparison-in-NET) library to inspectionate the sourcecode as an example for your needs

[image]

[image]

It reveals the difference between pixels and can compare images with a Similarity coefficient, I've write a basic example of both:

```
     Imports XnaFan.ImageComparison

    ' ===================================================
    ' Get percentage difference value between two images:
    ' ===================================================

    Dim img1 As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Image1.jpg")
    Dim img2 As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Image2.jpg")

    Dim PercentageDifference As Single =
        ImageTool.PercentageDifference(img1:=img1, img2:=img2, threshold:=3)

    MessageBox.Show(String.Format("Percentage Difference: {0}%",
                                  CSng(PercentageDifference * 100I).ToString("n1")))


    ' ========================================
    ' Get difference image between two images:
    ' ========================================

    Dim img1 As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Image1.jpg")
    Dim img2 As Image = Image.FromFile("C:\Image2.jpg")

    Dim DifferenceBitmap As Bitmap =
        ImageTool.GetDifferenceImage(img1:=img1,
                                     img2:=img2,
                                     adjustColorSchemeToMaxDifferenceFound:=True,
                                     absoluteText:=False)

    PictureBox1.Image = DifferenceBitmap
```

If you want something more complex you could use [AForge](http://www.aforgenet.com/) (Imaging) library to do the similarity comparison

Comment: This method is Awesome....now I need to figure out how to tap out the individual percentage shown in the tiny boxes. As I need to do a reporting system showing where is the problematic area. Thanks a lot guys @ElektroStudios and yu_ominae..